# Curved text created by fabric.curvedText.js not supporting loadFromJSON function

Tags: javascript, json, html, canvas, fabricjs

When I add curved text on canvas and convert canvas to JSON by using `JSON.stringify(canvas);` function, I am getting JSON like :

```
var front='{"objects":[{"type":"curvedText","originX":"center","originY":"center","left":180,"top":110,"width":149,"height":100.26,"fill":"rgb(0,0,0)","overlayFill":null,"stroke":null,"strokeWidth":1,"strokeDashArray":null,"strokeLineCap":"butt","strokeLineJoin":"miter","strokeMiterLimit":10,"scaleX":1,"scaleY":1,"angle":0,"flipX":false,"flipY":false,"opacity":1,"selectable":true,"hasControls":true,"hasBorders":true,"hasRotatingPoint":true,"transparentCorners":true,"perPixelTargetFind":false,"shadow":null,"visible":true,"clipTo":null,"text":"trstererer","fontSize":30,"fontWeight":"bold","fontFamily":"conv_bpreplayextended","fontStyle":"","lineHeight":1.3,"textDecoration":"","textShadow":"","textAlign":"center","path":null,"backgroundColor":"","textBackgroundColor":"","useNative":true,"radius":50,"spacing":15,"reverse":false,"bulge":true,"curve":false,"pintch":false,"arch":false,"wedge":false,"roof":false,"bridge":false,"vally":false}],"background":""}'
```

but error occurs when I want to load above json again On the canvas using `canvas.loadFromJSON(front);`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'async' of undefined
>   fabric.all.min.js:863 (anonymous function) fabric.all.min.js:863 v
>   fabric.all.min.js:860 fabric.util.object.extend._enlivenObjects
>   fabric.all.min.js:3719 fabric.util.object.extend.loadFromJSON
>   fabric.all.min.js:3700 (anonymous function)

Comment: The async property is missing. You have to add `fabric.CurvedText.async = false` to fabric.CurvedText.

Comment: thanks but I have tried this , no luck..

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle test case? Or can you post your fabric.js code.

Comment: https://github.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText/blob/master/fabric.curvedText.js

Comment: I have used code from above link and fabric.min.js also used

Comment: I am unable resolve this issue....

Comment: I have search on this and now I am getting error in the               var i = fabric.util.getKlass(e.type);                                                                               error:                                      Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'async' of undefined fabric.all.min.js:867
(anonymous function) fabric.all.min.js:867
v fabric.all.min.js:862
fabric.util.object.extend._enlivenObjects fabric.all.min.js:3737
fabric.util.object.extend.loadFromJSON fabric.all.min.js:3718
(anonymous function)

Comment: I am getting e.type as curvedText but I am unable to understand function getKlass . I am using fabric.all.min(1.2.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got solution to this problem.

I have added code from fabric.curvedText.js to the fabric.all.min

then issue of e.type undefined is solved.

then I have searched a lot on the getKlass and finally got solution :

**https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/oLDIW_MoRRY** here

I have given `type=curvedText` and class name as `fabric.CurvedText` which mismatches

now I have changed it to the   `fabric.Curvedtext` and what a surprise It works ...

Thank you Kangax n Yesh too.